# How do I make Auto Hotkey convert "RButton down, Mousewheel action, RButton up" into "MButton down, Mouse moving up & down, MButton up""

Tags: mouse, autohotkey, mouse-wheel

I got a program that zooms when pressing MButton while moving mouse up and down.

Because this seems a little bit odd to me, I decided to use AHK to let this program zoom when the mouse wheel is turned while RButton is depressed.

This is my non-working idea (commented out another non-working approach):

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Recommended for catching common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
SetTitleMatchMode, 1 ; 1: A window's title must start with the specified WinTitle to be a match.

#IfWinActive Zooming Viewer
~RButton & WheelDown::
    Click, up, right
    Click, down, middle
    Click, Rel, 0, 10, 0
    Click, up, middle
    Click, down, right
~RButton & WheelUp::
    Click, up, right
    Click, down, middle
    Click, Rel, 0, -10, 0
    Click, up, middle
    Click, down, right

;   MouseClick, R, , , , , U
;   MouseClick, M, , , , , D
;   MouseClick, , 0, -10, , , , R
;   MouseClick, M, , , , , U
;   MouseClick, R, , , , , D
```

Thanks for any hints to let me start this working, Peter

Comment: Does this Viewer has a separate command for "Zoom In" which you can do with keyboard? If not, then you have more or less correct approach in your script I think, but it is quite hard to tell what's wrong without having this software. So this does not work at all?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Mikhail V. This was the right suggestion, lead to founding that **Ctrl-Wheel** does the trick. Second, changing SendMode to "Event" gives additional stability. Third, "return" helps to isolate both zoom directions.

So, this works:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Recommended for catching common errors.
SendMode Event
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
SetTitleMatchMode, 1 ; 1: A window's title must start with the specified WinTitle to be a match.

#IfWinActive Zooming Viewer
~RButton & WheelDown::
    Send {Ctrl Down} {WheelUp} {Ctrl Up}
    return
~RButton & WheelUp::
    Send {Ctrl Down} {WheelDown} {Ctrl Up}
    return
```

Comment: Correcting Zoom direction anyway by exchanging WheelUp and WheelDown.

Comment: glad you've solved this. `return` is of course needed - it _must_ be there, unless the hotkey is only one line.