# How to let an Auto-Hotkey Script survive desktop-locking?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, autohotkey, desktop, mouse-wheel

I got an Auto-Hotkey script

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Recommended for catching common errors.
SendMode Event  ; Input worked hardly, "Event" is better.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
SetTitleMatchMode, 1 ; 1: A window's title must start with the specified WinTitle to be a match.

#IfWinActive Zooming Viewer
~RButton & WheelDown::
    Send {Ctrl Down} {WheelUp} {Ctrl Up}
    return
~RButton & WheelUp::
    Send {Ctrl Down} {WheelDown} {Ctrl Up}
    return
```

Ref.: [How do I make Auto Hotkey convert "RButton down, Mousewheel action, RButton up" into "MButton down, Mouse moving up & down, MButton up""](https://superuser.com/questions/1341223/how-do-i-make-auto-hotkey-convert-rbutton-down-mousewheel-action-rbutton-up/1341439#1341439)

How do I make this script surviving desktop lock on Win-7?
After freeing the locked computer, the viewer behaves as without AHK-script. Clicking on the script menu in notification area, chosing "Reload This Script" makes it work again – but forced to do so seems a little bit annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#Warn  ; Recommended for catching common errors.
SendMode Event  ; Input worked hardly, "Event" is better.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
SetTitleMatchMode, 1 ; 1: A window's title must start with the specified WinTitle to be a match.

MsgBox, Reloading

OnMessage(0x2b1,"WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE")
Gui,+LastFound
hwnd:=WinExist()
DllCall("Wtsapi32.dll\WTSRegisterSessionNotification","UInt",hwnd,"UInt",0)
    Return


#IfWinActive Zooming Viewer

    ~RButton & WheelDown::
        Send {Ctrl Down} {WheelUp} {Ctrl Up}
        return
    ~RButton & WheelUp::
        Send {Ctrl Down} {WheelDown} {Ctrl Up}
        return

#IfWinActive

WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE(wParam,lParam){
    static _0x1:="WTS_CONSOLE_CONNECT" ;A session was connected to the console terminal.
    ; ,_0x2:="WTS_CONSOLE_DISCONNECT" ;A session was disconnected from the console terminal.
    ; ,_0x3:="WTS_REMOTE_CONNECT" ;A session was connected to the remote terminal.
    ; ,_0x4:="WTS_REMOTE_DISCONNECT" ;A session was disconnected from the remote terminal.
    ,_0x5:="WTS_SESSION_LOGON" ;A user has logged on to the session.
    ; ,_0x6:="WTS_SESSION_LOGOFF" ;A user has logged off the session.
    ; ,_0x7:="WTS_SESSION_LOCK" ;A session has been locked.
    ,_0x8:="WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK" ;A session has been unlocked.
    ; ,_0x9:="WTS_SESSION_REMOTE_CONTROL" ;A session has changed its remote controlled status. To determine the status, call GetSystemMetrics and check the SM_REMOTECONTROL metric.
    Reload
}
```

https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/42717-how-to-execute-a-script-when-a-computer-is-locked/page-2#entry266488

Comment: According to the source, it is for "detect when workstation gets locked". I don't want to detect it, I just want to let the script survive locking (or rather unlocking?). If the script doesn't run anymore, how should detecting locking help?

Comment: On my system it works. I get the message "Reloading" after lockIng ( Win+L) and un-lockIng (signing in) the workstation.

Comment: Or did your mean to start another script that's supervising the other script and reloads it if necessary?

Comment: No, while the script is running I press Win+L and after signing in  I get the message "Reloading" from the same script.

Comment: If it works, I think there is another underlying problem, that becomes solved by restarting. If this script can detect unlocking, it should also do its real task – the scrollwheel translation. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Of course, it does it on my system. Have you tried it?

Comment: The line `MsgBox, Reloading` is only for testing the script. You can remove it if the script is working.